# How do I load a column using sqlloader if the CSV column is empty except for the header?

Tags: unix, sed, sql-loader

I would like to load a CSV file using sqlloader without having to edit the CSV file each time. When the file is sent to me, the data in the first column is only included in a header above the rest of that data. First code snippet is an example of what I'm receiving with fake data, second code snippet is what I would like to change it to.

Each row in the SQL table needs to include the number from row one.

```
1,Intern,
,1/8/2023,Bob
,5/3/2022,Alice
,7/25/2022,Charles
2,Assistant,
,1/8/2023,Heather
,5/3/2022,Harold
,7/25/2022,Dave
3,Manager,
,1/1/2023,Tim
,1/8/2023,Lyon
,5/3/2022,Greg
,7/25/2022,Tyler
5,Head Manager,
,1/8/2023,Charles
,5/3/2022,Zack
```

How I need it to look:

```
1,Intern,
1,1/8/2023,Bob
1,5/3/2022,Alice
1,7/25/2022,Charles
2,Assistant,
2,1/8/2023,Heather
2,5/3/2022,Harold
2,7/25/2022,Dave
3,Manager,
3,1/1/2023,Tim
3,1/8/2023,Lyon
3,5/3/2022,Greg
3,7/25/2022,Tyler
5,Head Manager,
5,1/8/2023,Charles
5,5/3/2022,Zack
```

I'm thinking there may be some way to edit them in the shell script that calls the sqlldr command, such as sed or awk.

Comment: Please, no use image format instance of  "text format" for examples

Comment: I agree that `awk` might be able to do this, but we need to see the original CSV file **as text**. Copy&paste it to the question and format it as a code block by using the `{}` tool of the editor field or by adding a separate line with exactly 3 tilde or backtick characters before and after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an input file (`input.csv`)  as shown in the question, the command

```
awk -F, -v 'OFS=,' '{ if($1!="") x=$1; else $1=x } 1' input.csv
```

prints

```
1,Intern,
1,1/8/2023,Bob
1,5/3/2022,Alice
1,7/25/2022,Charles
2,Assistant,
2,1/8/2023,Heather
2,5/3/2022,Harold
2,7/25/2022,Dave
3,Manager,
3,1/1/2023,Tim
3,1/8/2023,Lyon
3,5/3/2022,Greg
3,7/25/2022,Tyler
5,Head Manager,
5,1/8/2023,Charles
5,5/3/2022,Zack
```

Explanation:

- `-F,` set input field separator to `,`
- `-v 'OFS=,'` set output field separator `,`
- `if($1!="") x=$1` save non-empty value from column 1
- `else $1=x` replace empty value with saved value
- `1` always-true condition with default action `print` (shortcut for `{print}`)